# How to calculate differences across n columns in pandas rather than rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to look at differences across columns (or rows) in a large dataframe.
For rows I used the diff() method, but I cannot find the equivalent for columns.

This is a workaround

```
df.transpose().diff().transpose()
```

Is there a more efficient alternative?

Comment: Sorry you are looking at differences in a row with adjacent columns? [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html#pandas.DataFrame.sub) takes an axis arg which may be what you want

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pandas DataFrames are excellent for manipulating table-like data whose columns have different dtypes.

If subtracting across columns and rows both make sense, then it means all the values are the same *kind* of quantity. That *might* be an indication that you should be using a NumPy array instead of a Pandas DataFrame.

In any case, you can use `arr = df.values` to extract a NumPy array of the underlying data from the DataFrame. If all the columns share the same dtype, then the NumPy array will have the same dtype. (When the columns have different dtypes, `df.values` has `object` dtype).

Then you can compute the differences along rows or columns using [`np.diff(arr, axis=...)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), columns=list('ABCD'))
#    A  B   C   D
# 0  0  1   2   3
# 1  4  5   6   7
# 2  8  9  10  11

np.diff(df.values, axis=0)    # difference of the rows
# array([[4, 4, 4, 4],
#        [4, 4, 4, 4]])

np.diff(df.values, axis=1)    # difference of the columns
# array([[1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just difference the columns, e.g.

```
df['new_col'] = df['a'] - df['b']
```

For multiple columns, I believe unutbu's answer is the best (although it returns a np.ndarray object instead of a dataframe, it is still faster even after then converting it to a dataframe).

```
# Create a large dataframe.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1e6, 100))

%%timeit
np.diff(df.values, axis=1)

1 loops, best of 3: 450 ms per loop

%%timeit
df - df.shift(axis=1)

1 loops, best of 3: 727 ms per loop


%%timeit
df.T.diff().T

1 loops, best of 3: 1.52 s per loop
```

Comment: Not sure this is very efficient if you have a large DF, eg where # of cols > 2

Comment: Ahhh.... you meant all of the columns.  I've edited my response above and included some performance stats.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `axis` parameter in [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
#    A  B   C   D
# 0  0  1   2   3
# 1  4  5   6   7
# 2  8  9  10  11

df.diff(axis=1)            # subtracting column wise
#    A    B   C   D
# 0  NaN  1   1   1
# 1  NaN  1   1   1
# 2  NaN  1   1   1

df.diff()                  # subtracting row wise
#    A    B     C     D
# 0  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
# 1  4    4     4     4
# 2  4    4     4     4
```